# Estimate the order of the sum of probabilities

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Given $X_1,X_2,...,X_T$ as independent random variables from $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Let
$$M(T)=\sum_{t=1}^{T} \mathbb{P}(|X_t-\max_{i=1,...,t-1}X_i| \leq \epsilon).$$
Assume that $\epsilon<\sigma$. I am eager to know how to estimate the specific order of $M(T)$.

I have tried some methods, but without success. Additionally, through experiments, I found that $M(T)$ is significantly smaller than $T$, while what I want is an order of $o(T)$. And if it cannot be easily resolved, can restrictions be imposed on $\epsilon$?

Can anyone provide me with some hints? Thank you very much.

Comment: Does $X_{\max}$ depend on $t$?

Comment: $X_{max}$ is related to $t$, I have modified the question.

Comment: What the value of the max over the empty set (for $t=1$)?

Comment: Okey, we can start with t=2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $M_n=\max_{1\leq n} X_j$ with $X_j\sim N(0,1)$ without loss of generality. Denote $\Phi(x)=\Pr(X_j<x).$ Then $$\Pr(|X_n-M_{n-1}|<\epsilon|M_{n-1}=m)=\Phi(m+\epsilon)-\Phi(m-\epsilon)$$ and

$$\Pr(|X_n-M_{n-1})=(n-1)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\Phi(m+\epsilon)-\Phi(m-\epsilon))\Phi^{n-2}(m)\Phi'(m)dm.$$ Now use
$$\sum_{r=1}^Rrx^{r-1}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1-x^{R+1}}{1-x}=\frac{1-(R+1)x^R+Rx^{R+1}}{(1-x)^2}.\ \ (*)$$ We get the integral explicit form

$$M(T)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1-T\Phi^{T-1}(m)+(T-1)\Phi^T(m)}{(1-\Phi(m))^2}(\Phi(m+\epsilon)-\Phi(m-\epsilon))\Phi'(m)dm.$$

Comment: Looks like there are typos

Comment: Your analysis seems to apply to more than just the normal distribution. I've tried to estimate the integral you gave me, but I still have some trouble getting a concise bound that depends on $T$.

Comment: Using the anti-concentration inequality of the normal distribution, I calculate an upper bound on $M(T)$, which appears to be $O(e^{\sqrt{2\log(T)}})$ (ignoring smaller terms).