# Concentration bounds for dependent Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, concentration-of-measure

Let $X_0,X_1,...,X_T$ be independent random variables from $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.
Define $Y_t=\mathbb{1}\{ X_t > \max_{i=0,...,t-1}X_i \}$, then $\mathbb{E}[Y_t]=\text{Pr}(X_t > \max_{i=0,...,t-1}X_i)$.

What I want is a bound similar to Chernoff, i.e.,
$$\text{Pr}(\sum_{t=1}^{T}Y_t \geq (1+\delta)\sum_{t=1}^{T}\mathbb{E}[Y_t]) \leq \text{"a small value"}.$$

The method of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4809433/estimate-the-order-of-the-sum-of-probabilities)  can give the explicit form of $\sum_{t=1}^{T}\mathbb{E}[Y_t]$.

However, $Y_t$'s are not independent of each other, and martingale inequality doesn't seem to work here. To be specific,  this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354475/chernoff-type-bound-for-sum-of-bernoulli-random-variables-with-outcome-dependen) may be useful. But this bound holds for conditional expectations.

If the upper bound of Chernoff-type  is difficult to prove, is there a more relaxed bound?

I have done a lot of experiments with $T \in [10^3,10^8]$, and the results show that  $\sum_{t=1}^{T}Y_t \leq 2\sum_{t=1}^{T}\mathbb{E}[Y_t]$ is always true. The results are consistent when $X_i$'s come from a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From symmetry, since any of $X_0,X_1,\dots,X_t$ is equally likely to  be the largest one (and there are no ties as $X$s are continuous random variables) we get $\mathbb{P}(Y_t=1)=\frac1{t+1}$, so if $S=\sum_{t=1}^{T}Y_t$ then $\mathbb{E}[S]=\frac12+\frac13+\dots+\frac1{T+1}=\ln(T)+\gamma-1+o(1)$.

Also, $Y_i$'s are independent, as for $j>i$ the fact that $X_j$ is the largest amongst $X_0,X_1,\dots,X_i,X_{i+1},\dots, X_j$ is irrelevant to the fact that $X_i$ is the largest amongst $X_0,X_1,\dots,X_i$; *the second largest* amongst $X_0,X_1,\dots, X_j$ is equally likely to be any of $X_0,X_1,\dots, X_{j-1}$.

Hence $Var(S)=\sum_{k=2}^{T+1} \frac1k\left(1-\frac1k\right)=\mathbb{E}[T]+O(1)$.

Now you can use Chebyshev's inequality.

Comment: $Y_i$'s are independent is  hard to understand at first. Thank you.